# Microsoft calendar event response to Go struct

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-api

been trying to unmarshal a response from Microsoft's Graph API into a Go struct but I keep getting an error "json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field .value.start of type []struct { DateTime string "json:"dateTime""; TimeZone string "json:"timeZone"" }".

Below is my struct:

```
type MicrosoftCalendarEventsResponse struct {   
    Value []struct {
        Etag    string `json:"@odata.etag"`
        Id      string `json:"id"`
        Subject string `json:"subject"`
        Start   []struct {
            DateTime string `json:"dateTime"`
            TimeZone string `json:"timeZone"`
        } `json:"start"`
        End []struct {
            DateTime string `json:"dateTime"`
            TimeZone string `json:"timeZone"`
        } `json:"end"`
        OriginalStartTimeZone string `json:"originalStartTimeZone"`
        OriginalEndTimeZone   string `json:"originalEndTimeZone"`
        ICalUId                    string `json:"iCalUId"`
        ReminderMinutesBeforeStart int    `json:"reminderMinutesBeforeStart"`
        IsReminderOn               bool   `json:"isReminderOn"`
    } `json:"value"`
}
```

The response I received is this:

```
{"@odata.etag":"W/\"8COqS12xxxhwcMA==\"","id":"xxxxx","createdDateTime":"2019-12-05T17:09:41.018502Z","lastModifiedDateTime":"2019-12-05T17:09:41.8919929Z","changeKey":"xxxx","categories":[],"originalStartTimeZone":"W. Europe Standard Time","originalEndTimeZone":"W. Europe Standard Time","iCalUId":"xxx","reminderMinutesBeforeStart":15,"isReminderOn":true,"hasAttachments":false,"subject":"Something","bodyPreview":"","importance":"normal","sensitivity":"normal","isAllDay":false,"isCancelled":false,"isOrganizer":true,"responseRequested":true,"seriesMasterId":null,"showAs":"busy","type":"singleInstance","webLink":"xxx","onlineMeetingUrl":null,"isOnlineMeeting":false,"onlineMeetingProvider":"unknown","allowNewTimeProposals":true,"recurrence":null,"onlineMeeting":null,"responseStatus":{"response":"organizer","time":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"},"body":{"contentType":"html","content":""},"start":{"dateTime":"2019-12-17T17:00:00.0000000","timeZone":"UTC"},"end":{"dateTime":"2019-12-17T17:30:00.0000000","timeZone":"UTC"},"location":{"displayName":"","locationType":"default","uniqueIdType":"unknown","address":{},"coordinates":{}},"locations":[],"attendees":[],"organizer":{"emailAddress":{"name":"John Doe","address":"someone@somewhere.com"}}}
```

In which you can clearly see the part that is giving the error:

```
"start":{"dateTime":"2019-12-17T17:00:00.0000000","timeZone":"UTC"}
```

can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? been trying for hours without any progress and I really have no clue whats wrong.

The other stuff like Etag, Id, Subject and so on are working properly. Its only the nested []structs that do not work.

Comment: Can you post a (sanitized) example of the input JSON? This site is a good resource to convert complex JSON into compatible Go Structs: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! colm.anseo already gave the solution but anyways thanks for your reply and the link to the website, very useful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture calender events (plural) it makes sense that the top-level `Values` is a slice of structs.

However, within a particular `Value`, your `Start` and `End` fields are defined also as slices of structs which is probably not what you want.

Try just a plain struct:

```
Start struct {
        DateTime string `json:"dateTime"`
        TimeZone string `json:"timeZone"`
} `json:"start"`

End struct {
        DateTime string `json:"dateTime"`
        TimeZone string `json:"timeZone"`
} `json:"end"`
```

Comment: Oh man... so stupid of me... you are totally right! thanks so much colm.anseo that did the trick!